# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: m1 mac

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, apple-m1

```
 "__ZNSi6ignoreEv", referenced from:
          __Z2q2v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZNSi7getlineEPcl", referenced from:
          __Z2q2v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZNSirsERd", referenced from:
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZNSirsERi", referenced from:
          __Z2q2v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E", referenced from:
          __Z2q1v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZNSolsEd", referenced from:
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZNSolsEi", referenced from:
          __Z2q1v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q2v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev", referenced from:
          __Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev", referenced from:
          __Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE8setstateESt12_Ios_Iostate", referenced from:
          __ZStrsIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_istreamIT_T0_ES6_PS3_ in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZSt17__istream_extractRSiPcl", referenced from:
          __ZStrsIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_istreamIT_T0_ES6_PS3_ in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZSt3cin", referenced from:
          __Z2q1v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q2v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZSt4cout", referenced from:
          __Z2q1v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q2v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_", referenced from:
          __Z2q1v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc", referenced from:
          __Z2q1v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q2v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZdaPv", referenced from:
          __Z2q2v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__ZdlPvm", referenced from:
          __Z2q1v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "__Znam", referenced from:
          __Z2q1v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q2v in cc5SDSPY.o
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
      "___cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length", referenced from:
          __Z2q3v in cc5SDSPY.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Getting this error. I tried to install 'oh my zsh' and in the process, lost even the basic compiling setup.

Comment: What are you trying to compile? Are you trying to compile from IDE? Which compilers are you using?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Whoever is facing this error, this happens because of the Big Sur to Monterey update of the Mac os. Just set the code path again. Edit the JSON files and your vs code will again start working like a charm!

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I'm not following the "set the code path again" part, sorry.